# Antonym of "customized"

Tags: antonyms

We need to document a set of data processing rules. One of the rule is: "when the default style is changed, all items that have not yet been customized automatically receive these changes".

In a certain context, we need to use a phrase like: "changes to default style automatically propagate to un-customized items".

Is "un-customized" a valid word?

The antonyms dictionary we use lists "ready-made"; is "changes to default style automatically propagate to ready-made items" a valid phrase (it doesn't look like it is) ?.

Comment: more elaboration ... more example sentences may be helpful

Comment: The opposite of ready-made is bespoke (UK, but growing use in US) or custom-made (US). It can really only refer to actual things like clothing or houses.

Comment: Aren't all unchanged settings just other defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"non-customized"** is the right antonym.

There are other words you might use such as "generic" or "all-encompassing" but "non-customized" is the right antonym.

Answer (score 1):

In many contexts, ***off-the-peg*** or ***off the shelf*** would be appropriate. In this, I think ***unmodified*** or ***unedited*** might be pithier.